# How to batch resize an image and create multiple sizes (with Photoshop)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize, batch-processing, photoshop-scripting

I want to batch resize an image in multiple sizes with Photoshop.

The sizes are most of the time the same so I would like to have profiles for a set of fixed sizes.
Ideally I just need to open my source image and click on "Batch Profile #1" and then Photoshop is creating/saving X different sizes of that image as an output in a specific folder.

This is what i want:

[image: input output explanation]

Comment: I'm thinking... Action that saves the image 4 times... Or if you need more control, a script that does the same. Xtools for PS has a script that converts Actions into js, but you could also use the Scripting Listener plugin. On Mac you could use Automator to do this. There are also stand-alone mac apps that are made for creating different size assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a *Main* folder where to put the batched images and inside this folder make four more, one for each width: 1005, 640, 320 and 125.

Make an action and record this steps:

- **Menu File** > **Automate** > **Fit Image** insert only the width, for the height keep the same number: 30000 with **Don't Enlarge** option active.

[image: 1005]

- Save or Export for Web and Devices > Select the .jpg options > Save it in the *1005* folder.
- **Menu File** > **Automate** > **Fit Image**

[image: 640]

- Save or Export for Web and Devices > Select the .jpg options > Save it in the *640* folder.
- **Menu File** > **Automate** > **Fit Image**

[image: 320]

- Save or Export for Web and Devices > Select the .jpg options > Save it in the *320* folder.
- **Menu File** > **Automate** > **Fit Image**

[image: 125]

- Save or Export for Web and Devices > Select the .jpg options > Save it in the *125* folder.
- Stop the action

[image: Action]

- Make the Batch. For the destination select the *Main* folder and check **Override Action "Save As" Commands**.

Comment: It's good to know it. I never used Fit Image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, good suggestion.
But what about a change where I don't care about the aspect ratio?
With this solution it is working but only for either width or height.
Let's say I tried 1200x800 and 600x500. It won't work.

Comment: Ok, this exception wasn't at the question, my answer is exact to what you request in the question. In fact this exception is another question because there are several points to consider: do you want to maintain the proportions of the image or can it be distorted? Do you want to cut the image to the new ratio? From the center? from the upper left corner?

Comment: Okay, then let me add another task to that: Is it possible to crop images similar to your suggestion to specific dimensions with the center of the source image as the anchor?

Comment: Yes, but is a different procedure, and a different question.

Comment: Sorry, created a new question for it: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115938/how-to-batch-crop-an-image-and-create-multiple-sizes-with-photoshop